# Unobtrusive Validation not working in K-Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout-validation, knockout-mvc

I am using Knockoutmvc for my project.
Following is the code.

```
@using PerpetuumSoft.Knockout
@model OpManWeb.ViewModel.Customer.AddressVM

@{
    var ko = Html.CreateKnockoutContext();
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add/Edit Address";
}


    @Scripts.Render("~/jqueryval")

@using (ko.Html.Form("SaveContact", "Customer"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

     @ko.Html.TextBox(m => m.BlockNo, new { @class = "form-control fieldtextinput input-sm" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BlockNo)

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="margin-top:15px" />

}
@ko.apply(Model)
```

I have checked that it is working with Normal Html Helpers of MVC.
But with knockoutmvc it is not working.

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/unobtrusive-jquery-validation-for.html

Comment: I want answer for Knockoutmvc...

Comment: without scripting..simply same as Html Helpers

Comment: If it's not in the Knockout-MVC documentation then those helpers do not exist, you will have to either make your own or use JavaScript.

Comment: But how to write such script that validate data according to DataAnnotations declared for property inside ViewModel.?

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2013/04/unobtrusive-jquery-validation-for.html

Comment: In this example where is DataAnnotations accessed in script?